# Cannot unzip artifacts - need to answer to shell question

Tags: vue.js, web, deployment, server

I'm using Cleavr to deploy a Vue website on a server with Github Actions.

After the artifact retrieval this happens to the deployment process(that is automatic):

Logs:

```
    .......... .......... .......... .......... 73.7M
      1450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 72.3M
      1500K .......... .......... .......... ..                    59.9M=0.8s
    
    2021-10-01 20:53:16 (1.87 MB/s) - ‘20211002045301.zip’ saved [1568817]
    
    Archive:  20211002045301.zip
    replace dist/favicon.ico? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
    (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
      inflating: dist/js/about.41cd80a8.js.map  
      inflating: dist/js/about.41cd80a8.js  
      inflating: dist/js/app.9ea789b3.js.map  
      inflating: dist/js/app.9ea789b3.js
```

How can I answer the shell question?
I want to replace it!

Let me know if I can provide any other additional information

Answer (score 1):

I had to add -o in yml file in github workfile

```
- name: unzip artifact for deployment
  run: unzip -o release.zip
```